# Bison C++ multiple error recovery with missing semi colon

Tags: c++, bison, mode, panic, error-recovery

I'm developing my own compiler, and I have a problem with error recovery design
in panic mode for java grammar.

I thought about multiple solutions, but the real question:

How I could do that with bison c++?

I did that:

> package 2
>
> import java.lang.*;

error must consume to first semi colon and this run correctly with rule

> package_rule: PACKAGE error ';'

but if I wrote this code:

> package 2
>
> import java.lang.*
>
> class y { void method() { int m }
>
> }

what I need from parser like a standard compiler, to report errors:

> identifier expected at line of package.
>   missing ';' report one for package at import instruction line.
>   mssing ';' at int m line.

I mean I need after package error to consume token until the first semicolon or stop when find class or interface declaration at last line before declare them ! and report any other errors found after line:

> int m // missing ';'

please please help me, in my mind multiple solutions, but how do that with bison c++ for java grammar?

Answer (score 1):

You won't mind to solve that problem in the C++ OOP way, not in the bison way, would you?

Consider you have these kinds of AST node defined

```
struct BaseExpression {
    virtual std::string toIdentifier() = 0;
    // other member. remember to declare a virtual destructor
};

struct IntLiteral : BaseExpression {
    std::string toIdentifier() {
        error::toAnIdentifier();
        return "";
    }
};

struct Identifier: BaseExpression {
    std::string ident;

    explicit Identifier(std::string id) : ident(id) {}

    std::string toIdentifer() {
        return ident;
    }
};
```

Define a rule like this

```
%union {
    BaseExpression* expr_type;
}

%type <expr_type> simple_expr

package_expr: simple_expr
{
    $1->toIdentifer(); // thus integers or float numbers would generate errors
    // do sth with that identifer
}
;

package_expr: package_rule '.' simple_expr
{
    $3->toIdentifer(); // same trick
    // do sth with that identifer
}
;
```

where `simple_expr` is

```
simple_expr: int_literal { return new IntLiteral; }
           | ...
           | identifier { return new Identifier(yytext); }
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your basic problem is how do you want it to try to recover from syntax errors.  When you have an input sequence like

```
package x import
```

do you want it to assume there should have been a semicolon there, or do you want it to assume something else got stuck in before the semicolon and it should throw stuff away until it gets to a semicolon?

The latter is what you have -- the rule `package: PACKAGE error ';'` does precisely that -- whenever it sees the keyword `PACKAGE` but what come after it does not match the rest of the `package` rule, it should throw away input until it sees a `';'` and try to continue from there.

If you want the former, you would use a rule like `package: PACKAGE name error` -- if it sees `PACKAGE` with something that looks like a valid package name but no semicolon, treat it as if there was a semicolon there and try to continue.

Making it be able to do BOTH of the above things is extremely difficult.  The closest would be having the grammar look something like:

```
package: PACKAGE name ';'  /* normal package decl */
       | PACKAGE name      /* missing semicolon -- treat this as a semantic error */
       | PACKAGE error ';' /* no name -- skip up to the next semicolon to recover */
```

However, this sort of thing will probably give you grammar conflicts that are hard to resolve.

Comment: thanx for your answers, I made little mistake by explaining my problem.
pakcage 2 //here error in id and missing ';'
what I need to design professional compiler for java langauge that
matches standard one.
so your suggession Chris Dodd is goOd and I wrote it, but this either to 

discover error in id or in ';' but not both of them!!
what I need either consume error to next ';' in import with rule PACKAGEG 

error ';', or if not found to stop at last line before declare class, interface or EOF.
I need real advanced solution that gets same result in java standard, I'm waiting your suggestions..

Comment: Well, you could instead just use the rule `package: PACKAGE error`, or even `declaration: error`, which will attempt to recover at the top level from a syntax error without throwing any tokens away.  It will likely give you an error cascade, however (many 'false' errors caused by incomplete recovery)

Comment: package: PACKAGE error. the error token in this case take only first word after PACKAGE token then stop and this not my goal !! I want error token to consume all tokens before class or inteface if found.. then discover errors inside class or interface, clear ?? there's other problem in this solution, when write rule: > package: PACKAGE error  | PACKAGE error ';'  | ... then second rule it'll never be used !! real problem :(